# window.__coverage__ not showing anything after vue3 vitejs vite-plugin-istanbul configuration

Tags: vuejs3, code-coverage, e2e-testing, vite, istanbul

I am trying code coverage for my vue3 vite application. [Here are Vue3 vite app creation instructions](https://vuejs.org/guide/quick-start.html#with-build-tools). I am using `vite-plugin-istanbul` lib to instrument the code, but it is still not showing anything in `window.__coverage__` variable after configuration. My configurations are given below:

```js
// vite.config.ts

import istanbul from "vite-plugin-istanbul"

export default defineConfig({
  envPrefix: "FRONTEND_",
  plugins: [
    vue({
      template: { transformAssetUrls },
    }),
    istanbul({
      include: "src/*",
      exclude: ["node_modules", "test/"],
      extension: [".js", ".ts", ".vue"],
      requireEnv: true
    }),
  ],
  build: {
    sourcemap: true,
  },
})
```

```bash
# .env
VITE_COVERAGE=true
```

After this I run app `npm run dev`(i.e. npx vite) and trying `window.__coverage__` in browser console but getting `undefined`. I have set/export `VITE_COVERAGE=true` but still it is not working.

Answer (score 2):

You have declared `requireEnv: true` which means istanbul is expecting there to be the environment variable `VITE_COVERAGE` present and set to true in order to track files.

You should set `VITE_COVERAGE=true` inside your `.env.*` files and then try again. Alternatively, you can remove the `requireEnv` line and try that way, as Istanbul will instrument your code by default.

Comment: thanks micky for help! I have `VITE_COVERAGE=true` in my `.env.*` file and `requireEnv: true` but still it is not working. I forgot to maintain in question that "even after setting `VITE_COVERAGE=true` it is not working". It is only working when `requireEnv` is removed

Comment: updated the question. also added `forceBuildInstrument: true` as per suggestion here https://github.com/iFaxity/vite-plugin-istanbul/issues/40

Comment: If it works when `requireEnv` is removed, it seems the environment variable is not being picked up properly. Sorry, I can't offer much advice without taking a look at more code. Adding `VITE_COVERAGE=true` to my `.env.development` file seemed to do the trick for me.

Comment: thanks, Micky for the help. I found the bug(or new feat) in `vite-plugin-instanbul` here is details https://github.com/iFaxity/vite-plugin-istanbul/issues/41